# Problems with updating my graphics driver to Nvidia 430

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, ppa

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and following [this guide](https://github.com/lutris/lutris/wiki/Installing-drivers). When I entered `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` the terminal outputted this error message:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 2F7F0DA5FD5B64B9 home:strycore OBS Project <home:strycore@build.opensuse.org>
E: Repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease' changed its 'Label' value from 'Oracle Java (JDK) 8 Installer PPA' to 'Oracle Java (JDK) 8 Installer PPA (DISCONTINUED)'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
```

What should I do? How can I update the graphic driver?

Entering `sudo apt-install nvidia-driver-430` gives the error message:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-430 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-430 (= 430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-dkms-430 (= 430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-430 (= 430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-compute-430 (= 430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-430 (= 430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-decode-430 (= 430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-encode-430 (= 430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-utils-430 (= 430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-ifr1-430 (= 430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-compute-430:i386 (= 430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-decode-430:i386 (= 430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-encode-430:i386 (= 430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-ifr1-430:i386 (= 430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: The first error you are getting is not related to the graphics driver ppa but instead to the `webupd8team` ppa.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Nvidia 430 driver without adding any PPA.

sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=Nvidia&searchon=names&suite=bionic-updates&section=all

Comment: It just returned an error message about unmet dependencies and broken packages: